# Replace subsequent values of a column if a condition is met

Tags: r

I have a dataframe where I want to replace the values of a column till a certain number of rows if a condition is met

Example dataframe

```
A     B      C

10    15     0
11    11     6
3     12     0
4     6      9
5     9      0
7     8      0
7     1      8
```

If the value of any row in C is greater than 0, then the next 5 values of C need to be replaced with 0 resulting in the following dataframe

```
A     B      C

10    15     0
11    11     6
3     12     0
4     6      0
5     9      0
7     8      0
7     1      0
```

Any ways to achieve this without loops in R?

Comment: Is it truly "just the next 5 rows", or is it "all rows following"?

Comment: Next 5 rows. In the example accidentally both are true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, check `which(df$C > 0)`. For each element in the results, add `1:5` using `lapply`. Then, remove any duplicates in the results with `unique` (after `unlist`ing). Finally, make sure no rows are greater than `nrow(df)` with `pmin`, and set `df$C` equal to `0` for those rows.

```
df$C[pmin(nrow(df), unique(unlist(lapply(which(df$C > 0), `+`, 1:5))))] <- 0
```

Since you originally tagged `dplyr`, here's a tidyverse method (doesn't modify `df` unless you assign the result to `df`)

```
library(tidyverse)

inds <- 
  which(df$C > 0) %>% 
    map(~ . + 1:5) %>% 
    unlist %>% 
    unique %>% 
    pmin(nrow(df))

df %>% 
  mutate(C = replace(C, inds, 0))
```

edit: actually it seems like the `unique` step is unecessary. Not sure if there's any performance impact of leaving repeated indices in, or if so how that compares to using `unique`

Comment: I like the use of an array, btw ... array-ops could easily handle this in addition to window-ops ... and perhaps a little faster.

Answer (score 3):

This is a "rolling window" operation, so I suggest the use of `zoo::rollapply`.

```
dat <- read.table(header=TRUE, text='
A     B      C
10    15     0
11    11     6
3     12     0
4     6      9
5     9      0
7     8      0
7     1      8')

zoo::rollapply(dat$C, 5+1, FUN=function(a) {
  l <- length(a)
  if (any(a[-l] != 0)) 0 else a[l]
}, fill = NA, align = "right", partial = TRUE)
# [1] 0 6 0 0 0 0 0
```

(I used `5+1` to denote that we need one more than the rows we want to blank, as indicated by looking at `a[-l]`. Many thanks to @IceCreamToucan for pointing that out.)

Comment: I think the 8 would have been preserved as an 8 if this were just doing 4 rows rather than 5.

Comment: Bazinga. Nice catch, @IceCreamToucan.